# How to accelerate Webscraping using the combination of Request and BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The objective is to scrape multiple [pages](https://oatd.org/oatd/record?record=oai%5C:www.duo.uio.no%5C:10852%5C%2F8814&q=eeg) using `BeautifulSoup` whose input is from the `requests.get` module.

The steps are:

First load up the html using `requests`

```
page = requests.get('https://oatd.org/oatd/' + url_to_pass)
```

Then, scrape the `html` content using the definition below:

```
def get_each_page(page_soup):
    return dict(paper_author=page_soup.find(attrs={"itemprop": "name"}).text,
                paper_title=page_soup.find(attrs={"itemprop": "name"}).text)
```

Say, we have a hundred of unique url to be **scraped** `['record?record=handle\:11012\%2F16478&q=eeg'] * 100`, the whole process can be completed via the code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

def get_each_page(page_soup):
    return dict(paper_author=page_soup.find(attrs={"itemprop": "name"}).text,
                paper_title=page_soup.find(attrs={"itemprop": "name"}).text)

list_of_url = ['record?record=handle\:11012\%2F16478&q=eeg'] * 100 # In practice, there will be 100 diffrent unique sub-href. But for illustration purpose, we purposely duplicate the url
all_website_scrape = []
for url_to_pass in list_of_url:

    page = requests.get('https://oatd.org/oatd/' + url_to_pass)
    if page.status_code == 200:
        all_website_scrape.append(get_each_page(Soup(page.text, 'html.parser')))
```

However, each of the url is requested and scrape one each a time, hence in principle time consuming.

I wonder if there is other way to increase the performance of the above code that I am not aware of?

Comment: Take a look at `multithreading`.

Comment: You can also use ``gevent``

Comment: Checkout [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)

Comment: Look at distributed crawls in scrapy - https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#distributed-crawls

Answer (score 1):

realpython.com has a nice article about speeding up python scripts up with concurrency.

https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/

Using their example for threading, you can set the number of workers to execute multiple threads which increase the number of requests you can make at once.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
    import concurrent.futures
    import requests
    import threading
    import time
    
    def get_each_page(page_soup):
        return dict(paper_author=page_soup.find(attrs={"itemprop": "name"}).text,
                    paper_title=page_soup.find(attrs={"itemprop": "name"}).text)
    
    def get_session():
        if not hasattr(thread_local, "session"):
            thread_local.session = requests.Session()
        return thread_local.session
    
    def download_site(url_to_pass):
        session = get_session()
        page = session.get('https://oatd.org/oatd/' + url_to_pass, timeout=10)
        print(f"{page.status_code}: {page.reason}")
        if page.status_code == 200:
            all_website_scrape.append(get_each_page(Soup(page.text, 'html.parser')))
    
    def download_all_sites(sites):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
            executor.map(download_site, sites)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        list_of_url = ['record?record=handle\:11012\%2F16478&q=eeg'] * 100  # In practice, there will be 100 diffrent unique sub-href. But for illustration purpose, we purposely duplicate the url
        all_website_scrape = []
        thread_local = threading.local()
        start_time = time.time()
        download_all_sites(list_of_url)
        duration = time.time() - start_time
        print(f"Downloaded {len(all_website_scrape)} in {duration} seconds")
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link and the code. But, I should note that the suggested approach may result in the `website` denied the `request` as can be seen from the error [403: Forbidden](https://www.howtogeek.com/357785/what-is-a-403-forbidden-error-and-how-can-i-fix-it/)

Comment: No worries :) and yes I did see that as well. It's most likely the website rejecting multiple simultaneous requests from the same IP address. I've tested the same code with a different site, and I do not encounter any request being denied.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can use the threading module.
You can make the script multi threaded and go much faster.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

But if you are willing to change your mind ill recommend [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But for the time being, my overall framework base on BSoup