# Async request for list of URL in python

Tags: python, selenium, asynchronous, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have a list of urls (+500) that I need to get its html code, but it is very slow. Can I download them asynchronously?
Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def __get_html(browser, url, div_id, text_wait):
    browser.get(url)
    element_locator = (By.ID, div_id)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(element_locator, text_wait))
    table = browser.find_element_by_id(div_id)
    html_table = table.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    html_table = html_table.replace('amp;', '')
    browser.quit()
    return html_table

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_list = ['www.google.com', 'www.netflix.com', 'www.stackoverflow.com']
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    return [__get_html(browser, url, 'some_id', 'some_text') for url in url_list]
```

Comment: This can give some [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62859338/how-to-accelerate-webscraping-using-the-combination-of-request-and-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Its something like this:

```
import asyncio

async def func():
    #code to be exceuted
    await asyncio.sleep(10) #wait for 10secs
    #code to be executed

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(func(), func(), ...)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    time_to_run_function = time.perf_counter() #performance time
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have like 500 calls to the function to be asynchronously executed. How can I pass those 500 function calls with their arguments? Is there any way to wrap them up?

Comment: Call the function in a loop for the range you want

Comment: I redefined my `def __get_html` to `async def __get_html` and wrote `await` before the `browser.get(url)` line and `WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element(element_locator, text_wait))` line. Then made a lists of async tasks with `tasks = [__get_html(browser, url, 'some_div', 'some_text') for url in url_list]` and ran `asyncio.run(await asyncio.gather(*tasks))`. But I get `File "C:\...\xxx.py", line 45, in __get_html
    await browser.get(url)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression`